# i++ vs i+=1 in cycles, why evaluate?

Tags: c#, design

Why do most programmers use `i++` in cycles? Doesn't it mean *evaluate* and *increment*. I find more logical to use just an increment `i+=1`, because that's all I want.

`WriteLn(i++);` would evaluate i and then increment, does it somehow remove the *evaluation part* if `i++` is used in cycles?

Comment: Do you think that `i+=1` somehow does not evaluate `i`?

Comment: `i++` and `i+=1` are not the same.  You're thinking of `++i`.

Answer (score 5):

`i++` means "fetch the value of `i`, then increment it, and return the value fetched". It can be used in expressions to both get a value and increase it in one go. It can also be used as a statement:

```
i++;
```

in which case the value returned is discarded. In that case it's equivalent to `i += 1;`

When used in a loop, the same principle is being a applied:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
```

The former is shorter (and arguably easier to read), so has become the norm.

There is a caveat though in saying that they are equivalent. Consider the following code:

```
var i = 0;
Console.WriteLine(i++);
Console.WriteLine(i += 1);
Console.WriteLine(++i);
```

The output is `0`, `2` and `3` as the former reads then increments, whereas the other two increment then read.

Comment: So the "evaluation part" gets handled by a compiler and removes it if used in cycles, or just simple one line i++;

Comment: @Dereexk, firstly, they are loops, not cycles. You are making your questions harder to understand by using such an odd term ;) Regarding your question though, then you are close enough for me to say "yes". For a really accurate answer, write some code that both uses the value of `i` and doesn't and then examine the IL code that the compiler produces to understand what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There's no subtle technical reason for it. Using ++ is the more idiomatic form, probably because it saves one keystroke (or three if you put spaces around +=). The "evaluation part" will probably get optimized out in any langauge if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're counting keystones saved, don't forget the possible shift; + and = are on the same key in many layouts.